How to exclude everything under specific subdirectories via a SonarQube glob pattern?
I have a directory structure like this:
/
└-myapp
  ├- readme.md
  └- config
  |  └- staging.js
  |  └- production.js
  ├- src
  |  └- services
  |     └- utils.js
  |     └- timezone.ts
  |  └- controllers
  |     └- health.js
  |     └- user.module.ts
  ├- assets
  |  └- logo.png
  |  └- logo_small.png
  |  └- favicon.ico
  |- blub
  |  └- src
  |     └- which.jpg
  └- blub-e2e
  |  └- script.ts
  |  └- src
  |     └- what.jpg
  |     └- what.ts
  ...

I'd like to use the SonarQube configuration file sonar-project.properties to disable some rules for all files in all folders and subfolders within certain directories, in fact those directories containing the end-to-end tests (ending with -e2e, in the example aboce blub-e2e and below).
...
# Define rules to be ignored via ruleKey and for which files this should apply via resourceKey.
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria=e1
# Don't warn about console statements in files within e2e directories.
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.ruleKey=typescript:S106
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.resourceKey=**/!(*-e2e)/*.ts
...

Is this possible using the glob pattern? So far I came up with **/!(*-e2e)/*.*, but that only excludes the file script.ts directly under blub-e2e, but anything under blub-e2e/src/... is not excluded - you can see it on Glob tester.
